# Solving a Boolean Algebra Simplification via Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have been trying to simplify a boolean algebra expression,

( B+AC)~(A+B~C)+(AB~C).

Through thinking through it, and its truth table, I'm pretty sure the answer is (~A~B)+(AB~C).
I monkeyed with the algebra and removed the big bars which seemed important, giving me (~B+AC)((~A)(~B+~AC))+(AB~C) but I've gotten completely stuck as to how to make my way to my answer via algebra.

I'd love any advice on the steps to get where I'm going.

Comment: Is this symbol ~ concerning the letter before or after it? ... Isn't there a typo in the original expression?

Comment: It indicates a bar over the following thing.